# html5 video how to find out the different about seek start and pause

Tags: javascript, html, video

Visit http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html
   press the html5 videoplayer to play the video, if I drag the progress bar, the video is seeking now.
    but when I drag the progress bar, the 'pause' event also will be fired when the seek start.
     we only can get the seeking property true or false, but on the start of seeking, seeking property will be false. 
     just like this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_seeking
     so,it's make me confused how to check out which is pause,and which is seek start.

Comment: [current time](http://jsbin.com/ciceqayi/1/) [html 5 video player](http://cragglist.uphero.com/) [seekbar](http://jsbin.com/juyih/1/)

Comment: I dont't think this solved my problem, could you explan to me ?  thanks..

Comment: I didn't post this response.